How to combine DISTINCT with CASE WHEN or something similar?
I have a situation where I need to use DISTINCT to get unique values. But there is additional condition. In the duplicate rows I get some have a value SUCCESS and some have value FAILURE. I need it so that in the DISTINCT result, if any of the duplicates has a FAILURE then the DISTINCT result will have a failure, else it will be SUCCESS. How can i achieve this ?
SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2, COL3, Result (
     Select COL1, COL2, COL3, CASE WHEN resolved THEN 'SUCCESS' ELSE 'FAILURE' END as Result FROM table
     UNION
     // Some other queries with similar results
)


You can achieve that with GROUP BY:
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, MIN(Result)
FROM (<your table here>) t
GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL3


There might be more than 1 row with SUCCESS... so this would fail if i have 2 rows with success and 1 with fail

@MarkoTaht I see. Let me edit my answer:

@MarkoTaht try with MIN(Result), which will be FAILURE if any of the results was failure because FAILURE < SUCCESS alphabetically. If there are no FAILURE results, then it will proceed having it as SUCCESS

You can count 'FAILURE's directly.
See example
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
 ,case when sum(Result)>0 then 'FAILURE'
  else 'SUCCESS'
  end Result
FROM (
     Select COL1, COL2, COL3
       ,CASE WHEN resolved THEN 0 -- 'SUCCESS'
        ELSE 1 -- 'FAILURE'
        END as Result 
     FROM table
     UNION
     // Some other queries with similar results
)t
GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL3


You can use the distinct on clause and order the result according to the boolean value
select distinct on (col1, col2, col3) col1, col2, col3, 
          CASE WHEN resolved THEN 'SUCCESS' ELSE 'FAILURE' END as Result
from test
order by col1, col2, col3, resolved;

db fiddle

A combination of GROUP BY and BOOL_AND can be used to achieve the described results. The following query returns "SUCCESS" in result if all resolved are TRUE; otherwise, it returns "FAILURE" in result (this is consistent with the OP's original query):
SELECT col1, col2, col3, CASE WHEN BOOL_AND(COALESCE(resolved, FALSE)) THEN 'SUCCESS' ELSE 'FAILURE' END AS result
  FROM t
  GROUP BY col1, col2, col3;

This approach prevents repeating logic for mapping resolved to text values, which eases maintenance when the original values come from multiple sources such as the UNIONs in the OP's example query.
The following query treats resolved IS NULL as unknown instead of failure:
SELECT col1, col2, col3, CASE WHEN NOT BOOL_AND(resolved) THEN 'FAILURE'
                              WHEN BOOL_OR(resolved IS NULL) THEN 'UNKNOWN'
                              ELSE 'SUCCESS' END AS result
  FROM t
  GROUP BY col1, col2, col3;

The aggregate will be FALSE if any resolved is FALSE, but can only be TRUE if all resolved are TRUE.
